# Sorting Multidimensional Arrays with a variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm trying to pass a variable to a function to decide which array is a multidimensional array containing 3 arrays to sort by with the following:

```
wordData = [["john", "Bill", "Dan"],["Smith", "Adams", "Davidson"],[23, 45, 51]];

dataReader(1);

function dataReader(sortBy){

    wordData.sort(sortFunc)

    function sortFunc(a,b) {
        a = a[sortBy];
        b = b[sortBy];
        return a == b ? 0 : (a < b ? -1 : 1)
    }

}
```

I've set up a listbox later on with each array in 3 column, the variables are suppose to be paired so John, Smith and 23 are always in the same row. But I can't seem to get the sorting to work at all

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by, "it doesn't seem to work"?  What *does* it do?

Comment: Also your code actually does work perfectly.  You need to explain what you expect more clearly.

Comment: Also also variables "a" and "b" should be declared with `var`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to change the array afterwards in a 3 column listbox, is sortBy still being carried into the 2nd function?

Comment: If you don't elaborate on what's going on, **nobody can help**.  For example, what "3 column listbox" are you talking about?  I don't see any mention of that in the question. Why should sorting the array update the listbox?  Are you using some kind of framework for that? Etc etc etc.

Comment: @Pointy tanx i learned something new in javascript, you right, i delete my answer.. your comment is "That's just false. JavaScript always "hoists" functions up to the top of the scope. In other words, in JavaScript it doesn't matter where you put a function declaration - it's always interpreted as if it appeared at the top of the scope."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not sorting the right array. Try this:

```
wordData = [["john", "Bill", "Dan"],["Smith", "Adams", "Davidson"],[23, 45, 51]];

dataReader(1);

function dataReader(arrIndex){

    var arr=wordData[arrIndex];
    var bools=[];
    var tmpArr=[];

    arr.sort(sortFunc);

    for(var i=0, j=wordData.length; i<j; i++) {
        if(i!=arrIndex) {
            tmpArr=bools.slice(0);
            wordData[i].sort(sortArr);
        }
    }

    function sortFunc(a,b) {
        var which=(a == b) ? 0 : (a < b ? -1 : 1);
        bools.push(which);
        return which;
    }
    function sortArr(a,b) {
        return tmpArr.shift();
    }
}
```

arrIndex is probably better that sortBy, if I'm understanding you correctly.

Comment: This "solution" will only sort one of the arrays (the "Smith" array), and it'll sort it alphabetically.

Comment: Oh actually... I thought this was working, but it's not keeping the variables in order. John should always be beside Smith which should be beside 23.

Comment: Only one array is affected, arr[1] since you pass in 1. What's the behavior you're looking for?

Comment: @user1739337 I think I know what you're looking for. I just updated my answer. Try that.